# Selenium - Finding applied CSS Style

Tags: c#, css, selenium, webdriver

I have a webpage which has a field on it. The field values can be set using a config panel. That field can be marked as required by ticking a checkbox. This applies a style to the field label.
Now my question is using selenium how do I find out that this style has been applied to the control label?

```
    .form-group.required div.title label:after, .form-group.required label.title:after {
    content: '*';
    margin-left: 5px;
    color: #FF7900;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can try using getAttribute() to achieve your scenario

```
<input name="Name Locator" value="selenium">Hello</input>

driver.findElement(By.name("Name Locator")).getAttribute("value")
```

Here getAttribute() fetch the data of the attribute of value which is "Selenium". Returns: The attribute's current value or null if the value is not set.